# Custom links in menus not working in multiple environments

Tags: permalinks, staging

I have a top menu with links and for some of them I need to use "Custom links" instead of linking to pages. This mean I have to write [www.sitename.com/pagename](http://www.sitename.com/pagename) instead of Wordpress directly referring to the page for me with page linking. This all works fine on the live (production) site.

When testing I use a stageing environment. All page links now go to www.stage_sitename.com/pagename which is good. However, the custom ones still go to the production site since I have hard coded them.

I have tried to use /index.php/pagename (answer from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/how-to-add-a-custom-link-to-a-menu-with-a-url-that-is-relative-to-the-blog-url)). This will take me to something that looks like root/index.php/pagename. The problem is that my staging environment looks something like this: www.stage_sitename.com/~currentsite. Root will take me to www.stage_sitename.com/index.php/pagename but the real stage page is at www.stage_sitename.com/~currentsite/index.php/pagename. I hope you get what I mean :)

How can I use custom links in menus that will work for all environments?

Comment: Forgive me if this sounds like a dumb question, but are all the custom links to actual pages on the site (staging or live, as long as they live at the same domain)? It sounds that way to me based on your wording above....in which case, can you explain *why* you need to use a Custom Link? I occasionally use Custom Links for offsite URLs but don't see why to use them for on-site URLs....you can still change the navigation label and add classes to Page Links....

Comment: @Trisha, that is a very good question and I would like to not use them. However, e.g. the search page is provided by my theme template creator and the page is not in Pages. Therefore I cannot find it as a page when setting up the menu. I want to, but it is just not there.

Comment: Gotcha...so are you creating page links to pre-defined search terms? I think if you explain a bit more about *why* you're doing this, what end result you are building a link to, then we can probably offer some suggestions.  Normally you would not link to a Search Page in your menu, it's generally just a form field that appears on your website wherever you place it, often using the Search Widget, but some themes have a setting for it under Appearance>Customize where you can enable/disable it there, most Themes want to put it somewhere obvious like your header or close to your main navigation.

Comment: @Trisha, when creating the menu the page is not under "Pages", hence I cannot choose it as a page and need to link it as a Custom Link, if it was possible I would of course set the link as a page link. I got a site where you search for products where I have a complex search page with many filters and options, like any other retail store. Which I want to link to in my header titles, which would be pretty normal from my understanding.

Comment: It might work better for you to build a custom template, then create a Page called Search and in the Page Attribute choose your custom template, then you can link to it using Page Links.  

WP Codex info on Templates is here: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/

Here's a good tutorial on how to create your own Template file:
https://themeisle.com/blog/how-to-create-templates-in-wordpress/
There's also a TON of terrific plugins that give you lots of options and they often come with Templates you can use as is or modify, such as Search & Filter or FacetWP etc.

Comment: @Trisha, thank you, I will have a look at them :)